# I want to send users location via sms in android

Tags: android

I am trying to send users location via sms. I can get the users location but it takes lot time while the smsmanager sends the message with null value of location can somebody see my code or guide me what is wrong here. thanks!

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Button button;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener listener;
    private String gpslonla;
    private TextView t;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getlocation();
                sendlocationsms();

            }


            private void sendlocationsms() {
                String phoneNumber = "903399000";
                //Location location = new Location("dummyprovider");

                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                StringBuffer smsBody = new StringBuffer();
                smsBody.append("http://maps.google.com?q="+gpslonla);

                //smsBody.append(location.getLatitude());
                //smsBody.append(",");
                //smsBody.append(location.getLongitude());
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, smsBody.toString(), null, null);
                int gravity = Gravity.CENTER; // the position of toast
                int xOffset = 0; // horizontal offset from current gravity
                int yOffset = 0; // vertical offset from current gravity
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your message has been sent    ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setMargin(50, 50);
                toast.setGravity(gravity, xOffset, yOffset);
                toast.show();

            }

        });

    }

    private void getlocation() {

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                gpslonla=location.getLongitude() + "," + location.getLatitude();


            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        };
        configure_button();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 10:
                configure_button();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    void configure_button() {
        // first check for permissions
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                        , 10);
            }
            return;
        }
        // this code won't execute IF permissions are not allowed, because in the line above there is return statement.
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //noinspection MissingPermission
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, listener);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You fire getlocation(); sendlocationsms(); at the same time. How do you expect to send location at the same time when sms is sent?

Answer (score 1):

You must call the sendlocationsms() method when the location is received. Change your onClick method with:

EDITED:

Declare a boolean variable with initial value to false:

```
boolean needsToSendSms = false;
```

Then:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        needsToSendSms = true;
        getlocation();
    }
```

And call it when the location changes with

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        gpslonla=location.getLongitude() + "," + location.getLatitude();
        if(needsToSendSms) {
            sendlocationsms();
            needsToSendSms = false;
        }

    }
```

Adding the boolean variable makes to only send one sms per click.

I hope this helps.

Comment: this works thanks!! but it keeps sending the messages. like infinite! I just want to send one message

Comment: Create a boolean variable called needsToSendSms with initial value to false, then change the methods like my edited answer

Comment: I hope my edited answer works for you. If so, please mark the answer as correct again.

Comment: that doesn't work. I guess I have to apply requestSingleUpdate(String provider, PendingIntent intent) method instead of locationupdates method. but when i do that I get error in the pending intent parameter which is "listener"